# Spring MVC 3.2.8 Error 400--Bad Request

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a project based in Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework. The version of the Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework is 3.2.8

I have a JSP submitting a form

```
<form:form commandName="applicationForm" 
    name="applicationForm"
    id="applicationFormId" 
    method="post"
    action="${contextPath}/newdesign/manage/application/${applicationForm.application.id}" htmlEscape="yes">

<form:hidden path="application.id"/>

..


</form:form>
```

ApplicationForm class

```
public class ApplicationForm {

    Application application;

    public Application getApplication() {
        return application;
    }

    public void setApplication(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }
}
```

The class Application has this property

```
@Column(name = "ANDROID_TIME", length = 11)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date androidTime;
```

The curios thing is that if I put this property inside the for to sumbit

```
<form:input path="application.androidTime"  cssClass="form-control" disabled="${readonly}" />
```

I got this error in the browser

> Error 400--Bad Request
>
> From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:
>
> 10.4.1 400 Bad Request
>
> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed
>   syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without
>   modifications.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${applicationForm.application.androidTime}" var="dateString" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
<form:input path="application.androidTime"  value="${dateString}"   />
```